# MongoDB Query<T>.Where(Expr) converts number Types to string

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, linq

I'm using the MongoDB Query object to convert C# Expressions (Expression>) to JSON Query objects as seen here:

```
class TestObj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}

public void TestQueryMethod()
{
    var mongoquery = Query<TestObj>.Where(to => to.Age > 20);
    var queryjson  = mongoquery.ToJson(); // -> { "age" : { "$gt" : "20" }}
}
```

I want to send this JSON query string to my backend, which will parse the string into a mongoquery (which works well). The problem is the constant "age" (20) being converted into a string, while the database field is a numeric type. The database will therefore not return any objects...

I already took a look into the drivers source code, and constant expressions always are always parsed as strings:

From: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Legacy/Linq/Expressions/ExpressionFormatter.cs

```
 private void VisitValue(object value)
 {
     // [..]
     _sb.Append(value.ToString());
 }
```

UPDATE:
As I have no access to database collections in my frontend (the frontend only sends json queries), this solution won't work. I tried using the Builders class:

```
var query = Builders<T>.Filter.Where(iCompareCriteria).RenderToBsonDocument().ToJson();

public static BsonDocument RenderToBsonDocument<T>(this FilterDefinition<T> filter)
{
    var serializerRegistry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
    var documentSerializer = serializerRegistry.GetSerializer<T>();
    return filter.Render(documentSerializer, serializerRegistry);
}
```

But that's also generating a string value...

Comment: Is it possible  to upgrade your C# driver?

Comment: I already thought about that as I'm using parts of the legacy driver. But the newer builds do not offer the expression to json functionality.

Comment: Actually newer bits does provide this feature in couple of different ways. See my post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually tested your updated code and it produced the correct json values for both of the following usages.

```
var filter1 = Builders<TestObj>.Filter.Gt(t => t.Age, 20);
var json1 = filter1.RenderToBsonDocument().ToJson();
// Result: { "Age" : { "$gt" : 20 } }

var filter2 = Builders<TestObj>.Filter.Where(t => t.Age > 20);
var json2 = filter2.RenderToBsonDocument().ToJson();
// Result: { "Age" : { "$gt" : 20 } }
```

I'm using the MongoDB C# Driver version 2.2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log queries which C# driver send to server, you can modify `MongoClientSettings`

However, if you want simply extract JSON query what C# is generating, you can do so using `IFindFluent`

```
var query = collection.Find(s => s.StudentId == 0);
var jsonQuery = query.ToString();
```

jsonQuery will contain something like but depends on query.

```
find({ "student_id" : 0 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was I was comparing against a decimal type. The variable then gets casted from an integer to a decimal type var and as we all know mongodb can't serialize decimals... :(
Therefore it made a string out of it.